# jQuery date picker read date from text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I’m trying to read dates from a text file for example - '`08/12/2017`'

```
$.get('disableDays.txt', function(data) {
     var disableSpecificDays = data;
```

The values are getting read. I'm then trying to disable dates in the datepicker based on text file entries

It works when I set the value like this:

```
addDates: ['08/12/2017', '10/14/2017'],
```

This doesn’t work :

```
addDates:+ disableSpecificDays,
```

I’ve tried setting as array but I know jquery is not same as array and like:

`addDates:+ $('#disableSpecificDays').val,`

```
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
var dates = $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
            //addDates: ['08/12/2017', '10/14/2017'],
//addDates:+ $('#disableSpecificDays').val,
            addDates:+ disableSpecificDays,
                                    numberOfMonths: [3,4],
                                    defaultDate: '1/1/'+y                               
                            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
                            });
```

What I am doing wrong?

Can I write back to the text file with:

```
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Comment: please, format script source

Comment: Include an example of your "data"

Comment: addDates:+ $('#disableSpecificDays').val(); is missiing function

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: updated based on comments